How to handle stacking context in CSS in different scenarios like this one?
I have a table where the first column is sticky. When clicking a button within any row of the first column, a tooltip should open. However, the tooltip is partially hidden inside the adjacent sticky column in the next row.
I've prepared a complete code example to demonstrate the issue. You can run it in an online compiler to better understand the problem.
The problem occurs because the tooltip extends beyond its parent div and is obscured by the adjacent sticky column. How can I ensure the tooltip displays correctly without being hidden?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>HTML + CSS</title>

    <style>
      td:nth-child(1) {
        left: 0;
        position: sticky;
        z-index: 10;
        background: grey;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 60%; overflow: auto">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 1</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="height:100px">Column 1

              <button id='btn'>Click 1</button>
              <div id="tooltip" style="position: absolute;display: none; background: green; z-index: 1000; width: 100px;">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
            <td>Column </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

</table>
    </div>


    <script>
      const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
      const tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');
      btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        tooltip.style.display = 'block';
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>




check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73963059/tooltip-z-index-being-covered-by-other-element

Please edit your title. Phrase it as a question so it's findable when someone Googles this issue.

You don't need to set z-index to all the elements. Only set it to the td element that contains the popup


const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  tooltip.style.display = 'block';
});
td:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
  position: sticky;
  background: grey;
}

td:has(#tooltip) {
  z-index: 1;
}
<div style="width: 60%; overflow: auto">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="height:100px">Column 1

          <button id='btn'>Click 1</button>
          <div id="tooltip" style="position: absolute;display: none; background: green; width: 100px;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
        <td>Column </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>




Thanks for your response. But, here we can't use :has, because id or class is there for all the elements and it's visibility is handled dynamically based on data using ng-show.
And also... let's say if next td in next row also has popup class, then same issue would come.

@Sanjay all those detail need to belong into your question if you want to get accurate answers

Sure. I have resolved the issue by dynamically setting z-index in JS based on click event by increasing the z-index value to higher number for clicked element's closest 'td'. And set other 'td's z-index to lower value. But, anyways this answer is helpful for others who is facing similar issue. Thanks.
